# How can I able to display "No data" if there is no data in the json response in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

When there is no data, nothing is displayed. Can any one please help me to print a message as "No search reults" when data is null. I am doing a work for the first time and have only basic ideas.. Please help me with this concern?

My json data when data is null is:

```
{ "status": true, "data": [] }
```

```js
searchContent = new Vue({
  el: "#searchContent",
  data: {
    vector: {}
  }
});

categories = new Vue({
  el: '#categories',
  data: {
    category: 0,
    subcategory: 0,
    content: false
  },
  watch: {
    subcategory: function(e) {
      this.prefetch();
    },
    category: function(e) {
      this.prefetch();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    prefetch: function() {
      var filter = {};
      filter['category'] = this.category;
      filter['subcategory'] = this.subcategory;
      if (this.content !== false)
        this.content.abort()
      this.content = $.ajax({
        'url': 'filter/',
        data: filter,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(e) {
          window.searchContent.vector = e.data;
          console.log(e);
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="searchContent">
  <div v-for="row in vector">{{row.bussinessName}}</div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this completely in the markup. Try this...

```
<div id="searchContent">
  <div v-for="row in vector">{{row.bussinessName}}</div>
  <div v-if="vector.length === 0">No search results</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check data length in success.

```
success: function(e) {
       if(e.data.length > 0)
          window.searchContent.vector = e.data;
         else
           window.searchContent.vector= 'No search reults'
        }
```

Comment: some null values are printing

Comment: console.log(e.data.length) to check what is your length when data is empty.

Comment: 0 is coming/.. I need to display an image if there is no data